# What is the purpose of using testData in Angular Testing HTTP requests

Tags: angular, unit-testing

i have misunderstanding of using of testData from the angular's example of testing http service with HttpClientTestingModule.
My question is what is the possibility this `expect(data).toEqual(testData)` to be falsy.
When we actually doesn't send real request to the back-end or some Stub.

Link to the resource : https://angular.io/guide/http#expecting-and-answering-requests

```js
it('can test HttpClient.get', () => {
  const testData: Data = {name: 'Test Data'};

  // Make an HTTP GET request
  httpClient.get<Data>(testUrl)
    .subscribe(data =>
      // When observable resolves, result should match test data
      expect(data).toEqual(testData)
    );

  // The following `expectOne()` will match the request's URL.
  // If no requests or multiple requests matched that URL
  // `expectOne()` would throw.
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/data');

  // Assert that the request is a GET.
  expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  // Respond with mock data, causing Observable to resolve.
  // Subscribe callback asserts that correct data was returned.
  req.flush(testData);

  // Finally, assert that there are no outstanding requests.
  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance that `expect(data).toEqual(testData)` to be false in this case. What the guide want to tell you, is how to using `HttpTestingModule` to provide a fake response during the unit test.

[Here](https://github.com/yinnping/ng-test-sharing/blob/c5bdae369d2c5a991ec54271db3abcbe70da6dd1/src/app/services/helper.service.spec.ts#L24-L36) is some sample code uses `HttpTestingModule`.

```
it('shoud return { server: string; ixid: string; img: string }', () => {
  service.getImg(0).subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.server).toEqual('images.unsplash.com');
    expect(res.ixid).toEqual(
      'MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D'
    );
    expect(res.img).toContain('blob');
  });
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598188306155-25e400eb5078?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1934&q=80'
  );
  req.flush(new ArrayBuffer(1229));
});
```